# Get row if a number is inside a string range from a column

Tags: sql, postgresql

My table(with simplified columns) has this structure:

| brand | period | fuel |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Audi | 2008-2016 | G |
| BWM | 2018- | D |

The user will give me the matriculation year of the car and I want to look inside all the `period`s and find if the given year is inside the range.

For example `2010` would return me the `Audi` and `2020` should return the `BWM`.

My current query looks like the following:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM cars
WHERE brand='Audi' AND fuel='G' AND 
<userIntroducedYear> BETWEEN <year1> AND <year2>;
```

My guess is that I should be able to get this with some subquery instead of the `BETWEEN` but I'm a bit lost doing it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I suggest to split `period` into two distinct columns, e.g. `start_period`, `end_period`. It will make queries much easier and your query would work ;)

Comment: Agree about the structure, @Gordon Linoff query works well, but I think I prefer to restructure it as you say and use a simple query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should fix your data model so you are:

- Storing number values as numbers (years are numbers, not strings).
- Storing only one value in a scalar column.

Postgres offers an [range](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html) data type as well, which does exactly what you want.

For this, though, I'll just parse `period` into the period start and end years using `split_part()` and a lateral join to do the work in the `FROM` clause:

```
select c.*
from cars c cross join lateral
     (values (split_part(c.period, '-', 1)::int, nullif(split_part(c.period, '-', 2), '')::int)
     ) v(period_start, period_end)
where c.brand = 'Audi' and c.fuel = 'G' and
      v.period_start <= :userIntroducedYear and
      (v.period_end >= :userIntroducedYear or v.period_end is null);
```

Comment: Yes, you're right about the data structure, your query works but you need to fix it a little to get the year inside the range `>=` by `<=` and `<=` by `>=`. Crazy query, thanks a lot!